# Set run-time background-image after using camera plugin - ionic3

Tags: css, ionic3, runtime, background-image

I want to set a background image for my ion-content. 
I’d like to add it using 
`background-image: url('../assets/imgs/my_image.jpg')` in the CSS but I want the image to be uploaded from the user using the cordova-plugin-camera. As you know, with that plugin I can take a picture with the camera or upload it from the gallery, I can even display it in the HTML, but I have no idea how to set the background with that image.
I've tried

```
.content
{
    background-image: {{ myItem.photo }};
}
```

But obviously it doesn't work.

Anyone can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

This is how i upload the image:

HTML:

```
<button ion-button (click)="presentActionSheet()">
     Choose photo
</button>
```

TS:

```
public presentActionSheet()
{
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Load from gallery',
                handler: () =>
                {
                    this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Take picture',
                handler: () =>
                {
                    this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel'
            }
        ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
}

public takePicture(sourceType)
{
    // Create options for the Camera Dialog
    var options = {
        quality: 60,
        sourceType: sourceType,
        targetHeight: 500,
        targetWidth: 500,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        allowEdit: true
    };
    // Get the data of an image
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) =>
    {
        // Special handling for Android library
        if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY)
        {
            this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath).then(filePath =>
            {
                let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
                this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
            });
        }
        else
        {
            let currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            let correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        }
    }, (err) =>
    {
        this.presentToast('Error');
    });
}

// Create a new name for the image
private createFileName()
{
    var d = new Date(),
        n = d.getTime(),
        newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    return newFileName;
}

// Copy the image to a local folder
private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName)
{
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success =>
    {
        this.myItem.photo = newFileName;
    }, error =>
    {
        this.presentToast('Error');
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show the function to upload image

Comment: I added the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.content
{
    background-image: {{ myItem.photo }};
}
```

**Use `[style.background]`:**

```
<div class="content" [style.background]="'url('+myItem.photo+')'"></div>
```

**TS(component)**

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.myItem.photo ="your first url or empty string";
}
//Here you already set the url
private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName)
{
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success =>
    {
        this.myItem.photo = newFileName;
    }, error =>
    {
        this.presentToast('Error');
    });
}
```

Comment: @AlessioF tell me if it help

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: see my answer it work perfect:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906839/how-to-change-background-by-clicking-a-button/50907118#50907118

Comment: can you explain you issuse

Comment: If there is no photo it displays the default one I set (but not with the right size, it seems not to read 'background-size: contain'), but if there is a photo (I just did console.log to be sure and it is like "1529326905450.jpg") it displays no photo... just black

Comment: I tried to insert the [style.background]="'url('+myItem.photo+')'" in a <div> and in the <ion-content>... the only difference is that in <div> the screen is white and the first photo isn't displayed, whereas in <ion-content> the first photo is displayed with a wrong size and if I change that photo (uploading a new one like written before), black screen is displayed

Comment: do you save the photo that uploaded lockaly?

Comment: The way I manage photos is all above, nothing more. I thought I saved them with the copyFileToLocalDir function, but you make me think I made a mistake. How should I save them locally?

Comment: as I see here:https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/ you upload the image to tag. Am I right?

Comment: I can't understand what it means, sorry :/

Comment: what do you get in `imagePath` after upload

Comment: I've just did a console.log after `this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) =>...` to see the `imagePath` and it is like: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E2A6776B-237C-4BE4-95EB-ECCA0211975D/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg

Comment: fine this is the url so set it in the  param that you use in `<div class="content" [style.background]="'url('+myItem.photo+')'"></div>`

Comment: I got it! Your edit isn't the right way. I just did this: `<div class="content" [style.background]="'url('+pathForImage(myItem.photo)+')'"></div>`, where `pathForImage` is defined only this return:
`return normalizeURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + img);`. The only problem is that CSS property like `background-size: contain` is not respected... seems like not to read it

Comment: I return to previus version and I really appricate if you up vote and mark as answer

Comment: I will, thank you so much. And if you have any ideas on how set background like that with CSS I will appreciate it

Comment: it prefer to do it in this way

Comment: because not all browser support variables:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: I will, you've been so patient. Thank you so much

Comment: happy to help :)